# custom validation message in vee-validate

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-5.8, vee-validate

I am using Laravel - 5.8 with Vue.js. My question is about how to show a custom error message for a rule in the Vee-Validate library. My custom message for the "required" rule is not showing, and instead it reads: "The first_name field is required." The expected message is "Please enter first name."

**Below code is in app.js**

```js
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full';
```

**This is my HTML component code.**

```html
<template>    
    <div>
        <form role="form">
            <ValidationProvider name="first_name" :rules="required">
                <div slot-scope="{ errors }">
                    <input v-model="profileForm.first_name" class="form-control">
                    <p>{{ errors[0] }}</p>
                </div>
            </ValidationProvider>
                  
            <button type="button" @click="validateBeforeSubmit()">Update Profile</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Below is my JS script code**

```js
<script>
    import { localize } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full';
    import en from "vee-validate/dist/locale/en.json";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                profileForm: {
                    first_name: ''
                },
                customMessages: {
                    en: {
                        custom: {
                            'first_name': {
                                required: 'Please enter first name'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        created() {
            localize("en", this.customMessages);
        },
        methods: {
            validateBeforeSubmit() {
                this.$validator.validateAll();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`custom` keyword has been removed in version 3. It is now replaced with `fields`. **[Also this info was missing in docs](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2345#issuecomment-532667374)**

**[For more info please follow this issue link on github](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2345)**

Answer (score 10):

One way to do this generically, without attaching it to a specific language like with `localize`, is to use [`extend()`](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/extend.html#extend):

```js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: 'Please enter first name',
});
```

This will spread and include all the default properties of the rule, while still allowing you to add in your own custom message.

i18n Example:

```js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';
import i18n from 'localization';

extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: i18n.t('LOCALIZATION_PATH'),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple one. Although not good, but works.

```
<input name="yourFieldName" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="yourFieldName" v-validate="'alpha_spaces'">

<span class="small text-danger">{{ errors.first('yourFieldName')?'Your custome message':'' }}</span>
```

Comment: Clean and simple. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @pankaj for the right answer. For those who cant be bothered to follow the links, the documentation indicates the following solution:

```
import { localize } from 'vee-validate';

localize({
  en: {
    messages: {
      // generic rule messages...
    },
    fields: {
      password: {
        required: 'Password cannot be empty!',
        max: 'Are you really going to remember that?',
        min: 'Too few, you want to get doxed?'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With vee-validate 3

```
<ValidationProvider
  name="first_name"
  rules="required"
  :custom-messages="{required: 'Ooops, this is the message'}"
>
```

Comment: very useful custom way, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Custom messages can be added via 'extend' as @ zcoop98 showed. It should be noted that the property 'will be translated if we use it like this `message: () => i18n.t ('LOCALIZATION_PATH')`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29811904)

Comment: It has been some time since this publication was made. However, in 2023 it still helped me carry out a task I have in a project. Your solution allows translations to work. However, I can no longer access the {__field__} fields. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Janusz O found the answer: 
extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: (field) => field + ' ' + i18n.t('validations.mandatory'),
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass `this.customMessages.en` to `localize()` or the passed object has a top-level property `en`. The passed dictionary should [only contain your custom messages](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/#localize).

Comment: I have now this code: `localize("en", this.customMessages.en);`. This is still not showing me my custom messages